# How can I use a user defined function in a Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql, user-defined-functions

I have created a user defined function for Doctrine ORM inside my Symfony2 application, called `isnull_string()`. This is to be able to execute a query that would place null records at the bottom instead of the top, when ordering by ascending order on a string field. In MySQL it would look something like `SELECT * FROM airlines ORDER BY ISNULL(name), name;`

The function is registered in the global `config.yml` file, as instructed in the Symfony2 docs. But nowhere can I find any resources as how I could use this function inside the creation of a QueryBuilder object.

Here is what I'm doing to create my drop down menu:

```
 $builder->add('airline', 'entity', array('query_builder' 
       => function(EntityRepository $er){
              return $er->createQueryBuilder('airline')->orderBy('isnull_string(airline.name), airline.name', 'ASC');
          });
```

But it's returning a syntax error: `Expected end of string, got '('`

So how can I use this custom function inside the FormBuilderInterface?

Comment: Why not simply use `airline.name IS NULL, airline.name`?

Comment: I've tried `->orderBy('airline.name IS NULL, airline.name', 'ASC');` this too gives a syntax error: `Expected end of string, got 'IS'`

Comment: That's strange, because the docs [say otherwise](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#other-expressions). Its use is probably limited to `SELECT` and other. I'll do some more research.

Comment: Yeah I came across that as well, but I deduced that this freeform DQL is only available for the Query object but not the QueryBuilder object. If only the FormBuilderInterface would accept either type of object I'd be in the clear, but alas...

Appreciate any help you can give me though :)